# Does soldering to RJ45 magjack pins bypass magnetics?

Tags: ethernet

I am using a Homeplug AV device (2 wire ethernet) in a very tight enclosure, so much so that even connecting an RJ45 connector is difficult. I've found that if I solder my ethernet cable (which is only a 7cm cable going to a 4pin jst on a cctv camera) to the underside of the PCB (where the RJ45 magjack is soldered to the board), rather than use an RJ45, all seems to work fine.
However I'm concerned whether this bypasses the magnetics or not, and whether there may be issues down the track?
Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If it is a magjack connector, then soldering on to the connector pins does bypass the magnetics.

If it is not a magjack, it means there is a separate transformer, then soldering to the connector pins does not bypass the magnetics.

Comment: Thanks, how important are magjacks for short cable runs (eg 70mm)??

Comment: That has nothing to do with cable length. The point is that an Ethernet interface must have magnetics or it's not an Ethernet interface to begin with. Magjacks rarely even share the same pinout with plain 8P8C connectors.